# Python urllib2 -> urllib3 request.urlopen

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib3

I need to switch from urllib2 to urllib3. There is a problem with a request.

python2 code:

```
reqdata='{"PM1OBJ1":{"FREQ":"","U_AC":"","I_AC":"","P_AC":"","P_TOTAL":""}}'
response = urllib2.urlopen('http://'+ ipaddress +'/lala.cgi' ,data=reqdata)
```

python3 code:

```
reqdata={"PM1OBJ1":{"FREQ":"","U_AC":"","I_AC":"","P_AC":"","P_TOTAL":""}}
mydata = urllib.parse.urlencode(reqdata)
mydata = mydata.encode('ascii') # data should be bytes
response = urllib.request.urlopen('http://'+ ipaddress +'/lala.cgi', mydata)
```

When I use Wireshare for debugging I see that the reqdata under pythen2 is transmittet as string.
[image]

With python3 it looks like:

[image]

So how can I user urllib3 with the same output as urllib2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `PoolManager` class for the request, be sure to have urllib3 properly installed, then here is your modified code:

```
import urllib3
import json

ipaddress = "your_ip_address_here"
reqdata = {"PM1OBJ1": {"FREQ": "", "U_AC": "", "I_AC": "", "P_AC": "", "P_TOTAL": ""}}
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}

http = urllib3.PoolManager()
response = http.request(
    'POST',
    'http://' + ipaddress + '/lala.cgi',
    body=json.dumps(reqdata).encode('ascii'),
    headers=headers
)
```

Comment: Hi Saxtheowl, great the POST-request works. But the response seems to have another format than before. A comparsion of the response packets in Wireshark show that they are identical. Normally I do a jsondata = json.load(response), but now I got a JSONDecodeError

Comment: Hello, check if it is a valid JSON format with print(response.data) you may need to parse the response data differently if it is not

Comment: I got it. The solution is: jsondata = json.loads(response.data.decode("utf-8"))

Comment: Great :) dont forget to validate the question if it fixed your problem.